# Call javascript function into a link when it is printed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a little application with intel xdk I have already passed id values from one page to another. My problem is when I print some links in html I can't pass value from the other page. I'm trying by this way:

```
 <script>
     document.write("<a href='#' onclick='sendID('page2.html', '21')'>Link</a>");
</script>
```

I have passed id value from one page to another but in this case I need to pass from a printed link. Is it possible or there is another way. Thanks!

Also I don't know if there is another way to call a function that receives parameters when the link is printed.

More information. Into my head tag:

```
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Document</title>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         function sendID(dir, id)
         {
             dir +="?";
             nomVec = id.split(",");

             for (i=0; i<nomVec.length; i++){
                 dir += nomVec[i] + "=" + nomVec[i]+"&";
             }

             dir = dir.substring(0,dir.length-1);               
             location.href=dir; 
         } 
     </script>
 </head>
```

And in my body tag:

```
 <body>
     <a href="#" onclick="sendID('page2.html', '21')">Right link</a><br>
     <br>
     <br>

     <script>
         document.write("<a href='#' onclick='sendID(page2.html, 21)'>Link</a>");
     </script>
 </body>
```

In the first link the function is called and I get redirected to the other page, but in the printed link is doesn't work.

Comment: After document.write execution all that the document has is the anchor tag, no JavaScript function sendID, the information you have provided is vague and incomplete that it is not possible to provide an alternative solution.

Comment: I have written more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do something like this

```
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function sendID(dir, id)
     {
         dir +="?";
         nomVec = id.split(",");

         for (i=0; i<nomVec.length; i++){
             dir += nomVec[i] + "=" + nomVec[i]+"&";
         }

         return dir.substring(0,dir.length-1);               
     } 
 </script>  
     <script>
         document.write("<a href='" + sendID(page2.html, 21) + "'">Link</a>");
     </script>
 </body>
```

alternatively

you can also do a document.write(`<<escape and put the sendID javascript function here>>`) following by the document.write that prints the anchor tag.

Comment: By the first way I get redirect inmediately to the second page, that code is a n example. I have a page with a while loop in which I am displaying subcategories of productos when I click on them I have to get redirected to the product page. That's why I'm trying something like this because I need to click on them and pass its id to the product page. So, I print the subcategories and each one has a link (an a tag) that's why it has to be made by this way.

Comment: Oh you were actually setting the location.href, that is why, I have edited it to just return the href

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">

</style>

   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Document</title>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         function sendID(dir, id)
         {
             dir +="?";
             nomVec = id.split(",");

             for (i=0; i<nomVec.length; i++){
                 dir += nomVec[i] + "=" + nomVec[i]+"&";
             }

             dir = dir.substring(0,dir.length-1);               
             location.href=dir; 
         } 
     </script>
 </head>

<body>
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="sendID('page2.html','21');">click here</a>
     <br>
     <br>

     <script>
         document.write("<a href='#' onclick='sendID(page2.html, 21)'>Link</a>");
     </script>
 </body>

</body>
</html>
```